# Natural 1 on critical confirmation roll

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat, critical-hit

If you roll a natural 20 to hit (for a potential critical hit), then roll a natural 1 on the confirmation roll, can you still confirm the critical hit?

Answer (score 14):

## A natural 1 on the confirmation roll automatically fails to confirm the critical hit

On [**Critical Hits**](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Gamemastering/combat/#Critical_Hits), in part, says, "To find out if [a threat is] a critical hit, you immediately make an attempt to 'confirm' the critical hit—**another attack roll** with all the same modifiers as the attack roll you just made. If the confirmation roll also results in **a hit** against the target’s AC, your original hit is a critical hit." (emphases mine).

On [**Automatic Hits and Misses**](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Gamemastering/combat/#Automatic_Misses_and_Hits), in part, says, "A natural 1 (the d20 comes up 1) on an attack roll is always a miss."

Thus, because the roll to confirm a critical hit is an attack roll, the roll to confirm automatically misses on a natural 1, and the attack is a normal hit rather than a critical hit.